# Adding triggers and tables to MBS databases

Tags: sql-server, triggers

does anyone have experiences whether it's possbile to add triggers and custom tables
to MBS systems? To be more exact: I want to add a trigger and table to a Microsoft
CRM installation in order track several changes to some records in the system.

Is that a possible way to go or are there any technical / legal issues which
make this a NoNo?

EDIT: The trigger should fill that custom table, nothing more.

thanks in advance

K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technical issues - you could potentially add breaking code by doing this. You have to be careful adding triggers. If you want to track changes, there are several change capture tools (including native change capture in SQL 2008 to help with this).

IANAA, but benerally modifying the structure of you database will void your warranty / support agreement. Read your agreement carefully for this.

Comment: thanks raj; so I guess I'll have to do some reading on MBS plugin interfaces. ;)